# IPv6 Causes TCP SSL requests to Microsoft CDNs to fail (connection reset)

Tags: ssl, tcp, ipv6, connection

**NOTE:** The following only applies if I enable IPv6. If I disable IPv6 via control panel/adapter settings in Windows everything works fine. See latest update at bottom.

---

- Windows 10 Desktop
- -> Wired Ethernet connection
- -> Linksys EA3500 router running OpenWRT (r49377)
- -> TWC modem setup as passthrough

SSL TCP requests from my desktop to several of Microsoft's CDNs fail with a connection reset error. Example domains:

```
https://go.microsoft.com
https://i.s-microsoft.com
https://c.s-microsoft.com
https://assets.onestore.ms
```

However, other Microsoft domains (like `www.microsoft.com`) work fine.

**Fiddler capture:** https://gist.github.com/yo1dog/46d2604c9dc9c84b2de7225ebc25b263

**Wireshark capture:** http://yo1.dog/share/microsoftReset.pcapng

Note: Firefox auto-retries 10 times which is why there are 10 failed requests.

As you can see, the server kills the connection during the handshake. From the fiddler capture: `HTTPS handshake to go.microsoft.com (for #1) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` I don't really know how to read the Wireshark stuff but it also shows the connection rest: `[RST, ACK]`.

- I haven't noticed this problem with any other websites or services.
- Running a fresh (1-2 weeks old) install of Windows 10 64bit.
- Noticed the problem for the first time today. I *think* I was not having this problem about 1 week ago.
- Haven't changed anything with Windows Firewall or any proxy settings that I can think of.
- I haven't made any changes to my router or modem.
- This problem does not occur on any of my mobile devices connected to the same router via wifi (I don't have another device with an Ethernet port).
- I have tried different methods of requesting: Firefox, IE, and `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString` in PowerShell.

If I go to microsoft.com in my browser, the page is all messed up because most of the CSS and JavaScript is not loaded because they are served from those CDNs. Is this happening to anyone else?

Any ideas/debugging suggestions?

---

**Update:** Some requests are now going through as expected and some are still failing. I am guessing this means that the CDN is having issues with some of their proxy servers. For now I will just keep retrying and hope I get a good server.

---

**Update:** 3 Days later and still experiencing this problem. I haven't seen anyone else complain about this issue. I am going back to thinking the problem is on my end, but I have no idea what it is.

---

**Update:** I found that everything works as normal when I disable IPv6 in Windows control panel/adapter settings. Why does enabling IPv6 cause SSL connection attempts to Microsoft CDNs to fail?

Comment: Your packet capture contains only IPv6 connection attempts. I suspect the problem is going to be on Akamai's end, not yours.

Comment: Yea since the server is the one killing the connection I first assumed the problem was on their side. But if that's true, why is only my desktop having this issue and my other devices are not?

Mind checking https://www.microsoft.com for me? Does it look fine to you?

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Possibly related: [I have IPv6. Why does my connection to the Windows Store fail?](http://superuser.com/q/497823/144961)

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? It's 2022 and I've got this issue on a brand new laptop. Disabling IPv6 seemed to fix it. I also saw it on my old computer, although in that case switching from wired ethernet to WiFi seemed to fix it. It only seems to be Microsoft domains which have the issue for me as well.

Comment: I did not. IPv6 has always been spotty for me. I've had it disabled for a long time.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem here with IPv6 enabled. I spoke to my ISP, provided Wireshark logs and we couldn't solve it. I assume problem is at MS end too.

This affects Outlook for web too, sometimes the page won't load up and I'll have to restart.